# Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements when using EXEC sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server stored procedure which is being called from other procedure. I am creating dynamic SQL `@cmd` and if I am running that dynamic SQL using `EXEC sp_executesql @cmd = @cmd` instead of `EXEC @cmd`.

This call is failing with an error

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1

Here's my code:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateTable
    @base_name varchar(50),
    @partition_slot bigint,
    @partition_slot_end bigint,
    @out_partition_name varchar(50) OUTPUT
AS
    ---------------------------------------------
    DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
    DECLARE @partition_name varchar(50)

    --------------------------------------------
    -- set session variables
    ---------------------------------------------
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON 

    ---------------------------------------------
    -- body of stored procedure
    ---------------------------------------------
    SELECT @partition_name = NULL

    IF @base_name = 'AggTrade'
    BEGIN
        SELECT @partition_name = CONVERT(varchar(50), dbo.TimeSliceToDatetime(@partition_slot), 112)
        SELECT @cmd = 'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + @base_name + @partition_name
                      +' ('
                      +' exchange varchar(10) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS not null,'
                      +' symbol varchar(30) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS not null,'
                      +' timeslice bigint not null  constraint CK__'+ @base_name +   @partition_name + '__timeslice check (timeslice >= convert(bigint, ' + CONVERT( VARCHAR(50), @partition_slot ) + ') AND timeslice <= convert(bigint, ' + CONVERT( VARCHAR(50), @partition_slot_end ) + ') ),'
                      + ' condition smallint not null,'
                      + ' price float not null,'
                      + ' [size] bigint not null,'
                      + ' volume bigint not null,'
                      + ' sequenceno bigint not null,'
                      + ' totalValue float,'
                      + ' constraint PKC__' + @base_name + @partition_name +  '__exchange_symbol_timeslice_sequenceno_condition  primary key clustered(exchange, symbol, timeslice, sequenceno, condition)'
                      + ' ) on [Trades]'

        PRINT @cmd --tmp
        EXEC sp_executesql @cmd =@cmd
    END

    SELECT @out_partition_name = @partition_name
    PRINT @out_partition_name
GO
```

Comment: `EXEC sp_executesql @cmd =@cmd` is wrong, it should be `EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @cmd;` or just `EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;` The real question is why you are creating tables dynamically anyway. Don't store data in object names. This could just as well always be one fixed table, which a `Datetime` column

Answer (score 3):

Never declare `nvarchar` or `varchar` without a length since the default length is 1. This causes the create table statement to be truncated to only 'c` so you should have gotten error "Could not find stored procedure 'c'.". The error aand transaction handling in the outer proc is suspect if the error is not reported and the transaction count isn't zero on exit.

Add the length to the @cmd variable declaration to fix this error:

```
declare @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
```

**EDIT:**

I see you edited the script in your question to change the declare to `declare @cmd varchar(1000)`. That may avoid the truncation error but I suggest `nvarchar(MAX)` since that's what `sp_executesql` expects.

Comment: @Himani, there is also a bug in the outer proc. I suggest you fix that too and ask another question if you need help with it.

Comment: Changing to a `varchar` actually causes the above to fail, the input command *must" be an `nvarchar`: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nGIg_FIS)